# How to remove the cursor line from a C# Console Application?

Tags: c#, console

I have already managed to remove the cursor itself with `Console.CursorVisible = false;`. However, the line that the cursor exists in still takes up space at the bottom of my program. In other words, I would like to print to my console so that it fills the entire console screen. Here's an image of how it currently looks, with the bottom row not getting filled.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Can you show what you're doing to fill up the space? The solution may just be as simple as using Console.Write() instead of Console.WriteLine() so that it doesn't automatically make a new line, which in turn shouldn't create that empty line at the bottom

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I am using Console.Write. It automatically makes a new line after the Console runs out of horizontal space. The issue is that once the line on top of the bottom-most line fills up, instead of filling the bottom-most line, the Console simply pushes the lines up, always leaving the bottom line blank.